# How to convert string to datetime that with million seconds?

Tags: c#

I have a string which value is "2016-01-07 20:43:01,803".

I'd like to convert it use DateTime.Parse method. it is failed.

How to convert to datetime with this type of string?

Comment: Use `ParseExact`, and specify the format.

Comment: There are tons of such questions in SO. I even dont know which to choose for duplicate. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ParseExact` method.

```
var input = "2016-01-07 20:43:01,803";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Note the comma vs period...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you very much !

Comment: @Joey Why not ? I just tried it in my VS and it worked.

Comment: @Christos: Yeah, sorry, got confused with numeric format strings, but the DateTime ones don't even specify `.` or `,` so they bear no meaning to the format string.

Comment: The decimal point isn't treated in a culture-sensitive manner in date/time patterns anway, oddly enough. Even more oddly, ISO-8601 allows both period and comma, but *prefers* comma... but most implementations seem to have ignored that.

Comment: @Joey Not a problem at all :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the **right format**. (the last phrase is *very very* important: [right format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-01-07 20:43:01,803", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", null);
```